# Softmax input dimension in the Pyfaster RCNN ZF network model

Tags: caffe, softmax

I am interested in reproducing the steps in the prototxt file for zf net. The part I am unsure about is the softmax layer.  rpn_cls_score is created with dimensions (1,18,h,w) here:

```
layer {
  name: "rpn_cls_score"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "rpn/output"
  top: "rpn_cls_score"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 18   # 2(bg/fg) * 9(anchors)
    kernel_size: 1 pad: 0 stride: 1
    weight_filler { type: "gaussian" std: 0.01 }
    bias_filler { type: "constant" value: 0 }
  }
}
```

Then it is reshaped to dimensions (1,2,9*h,w) here:

```
layer {
   bottom: "rpn_cls_score"
   top: "rpn_cls_score_reshape"
   name: "rpn_cls_score_reshape"
   type: "Reshape"
   reshape_param { shape { dim: 0 dim: 2 dim: -1 dim: 0 } }
}
```

Finally it is passed to softmax:

```
layer {
  name: "rpn_cls_prob"
  type: "Softmax"
  bottom: "rpn_cls_score_reshape"
  top: "rpn_cls_prob"
}
```

My question is this. According to the caffe online documentation, softmax takes a 1-dimensional input, but rpn_cls_score_reshape has dimensions (1,2,9*h,w). Does the softmax sum over all indices, or does it select a canonical axis and sum only over the remaining indices (as the C++ code seems to indicate)? In this case, that would mean that it divides rpn_cls_score_reshape into two arrays, (1,channel=1,9*h,w) and (1,channel=2,9*h,w), one for each value of the second index, and in each one performs the softmax by summing the exponentials of the 9*h*w components, then reassembles them into an array with the original dimensions (1,2,9*h,w) and returns this as rpn_cls_prob. If not, how does softmax handle an input array with more than one dimension?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `SofmaxParameter` is documented in [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto), it has a parameter axis which is set by default to 1:

```
// The axis along which to perform the softmax -- may be negative to index
// from the end (e.g., -1 for the last axis).
// Any other axes will be evaluated as independent softmaxes.
optional int32 axis = 2 [default = 1];
```

So your understanding for the C++ implementation is correct, and for the question on how softmax handles ND input with N > 1 is that each axis is evaluated separately.
As for faster-RCNN, if you're interested in the foreground boxes only, you can just split rpn_cls_score blob and use only it's second half (i.e. after training your network set `num_output: 9 # instead of 18`, or during training use `Slice` layer to take the second half only). Pay attention to change the caffemodel accordingly, in case you train as usual and change `num_output` after training.